# Injecting EntityManager in JBoss/WildFly

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I am learning JPA, EJB and JBoss/WildFly.

I need to inject an `EntityManager` into my application. I am trying to do it in the following way:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ProductsService implements IProductsService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myUnit")
    EntityManager entityManager;

//....
}
```

And I have `persistence.xml` file in the `META-INF` directory in my `.war` archive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myUnit">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source> 
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The JNDI data source (`java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS`) is the default data source that is provided in a clean WildFly installation.

When I deploy my application to WildFly I get the following error:

```
JBAS011440: Can't find a persistence unit named myUnit in deployment "my-web-app.war".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`persistence.xml` always resides in `{root-of-persistence-unit}/META-INF/ directory`. In a war file you must place the `persistence.xml` in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`.

Eg:

```
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
WEB-INF/web.xml
```

See more: [Persistence Units](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbrj/index.html)